# How can I make this recursive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, multidimensional-array

Including the declaration of the 2d Array, how can I make the following recursive?  I would like it to iterate until there are no "children()".

```
    self.buildRelationships = function () {
        relationships = [];
        relationships[0] = [];
        relationships[1] = [];
        relationships[2] = [];
        relationships[3] = [];
        relationships[0][0] = self.name();
        $.each(self.children(), function(i, child) {
            relationships[1][i] = child.name();
            $.each(child.children(), function (j, grandchild) {
                relationships[2][j] = grandchild.name();
                $.each(grandchild.children(), function (k, greatgrandchild) {
                    relationships[3][k] = greatgrandchild.name();
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

## Visualization of objective

#### Given this data:

- Me!

  - Bob

    - James

      - Dale
    - Steve
  - Bill

    - Fred

      - Owen
      - Patrick

#### .children() returns immediate children only:

Bob.children() would return "James" and "Steve".

Me!.children() would return "Bob" and "Bill".

#### The accepted answer would create data that looked like this:

```
relationships[0] = "Me!" //this will always have a length of only 1
relationships[1] = "Bob", "Bill"
relationships[2] = "James", "Steve", "Fred"
relationships[3] = "Dale", "Owen", "Patrick"
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using $.each? It seems like a lot of overhead for no reason.

Comment: The only reason is familiarity.  Any iterative function would be fine.

Comment: It looks like you're leaking `relationships` into the global namespace, btw

Comment: I'd recommend changing it, it's confusing, not convention, and expensive.Each was designed primarily to iterate over dom elements. Secondly this appears like you're doing 3 layers of loops for a 2 dimensional array? Sounds like the data you're dealing with is actually 3 dimensional. I could be wrong.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: `$.each` is a generic method to iterate over arrays and objects. And even `$(...).each` wouldn't be very expensive since it just iterates over the already selected elements. There is no DOM interaction happening at that point.

Comment: I'm building a "relationship map", called "relationships".  the first [] is the generation, the second is a list of the items in that generation.  Open to any improvements...

Comment: I'd highly recommend just returning `relationships` and not relying on global variables. Also, assuming each child has its own children, you are overwriting each level greater than 1 in your array.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm sure it can.. http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: Of course native loops are more performant. But *"Each was designed primarily to iterate over dom elements"* is incorrect. The reason why `$.each` (or `$(...).each(..)`) is less performant is not that it was designed to iterate over DOM element, but because it involves a function call per iteration and maybe other checks. The benefit is that each iteration has its own scope. In general it's unlikely that this is the bottleneck of an application.

Comment: @FelixKling Why would you design a duplicate of a thing which is slower. Clearly its invented purpose was to iterate over DOM elements.

Even according to the JQuery API Docs.. The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone.

Comment: Updated question to better explain my goal.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: I'd personally opt for `$.each` (or better yet, `_.each`), unless I was in a performance-critical section. The difference is negligible for the number of items a person typically iterates over, especially compared to the real application bottlenecks. I prefer the scoping introduced by the closures.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: Really? Where does it say that? Please show me: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ Also arrays of a native `forEach` method which works similar to `$.each`. Why would they add it? Because it's great for functional programming.

Comment: @acjohnson55 wasted cycles work for hitler.

Comment: @FelixKling Use map. It's in the language.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: Uh? I *just* said [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a native method. `.map` and `.forEach` are different. Anyways, not the right place to discuss this. I respect your opinion (use the faster way), but don't make false statements (`$.each` was designed to iterate over DOM elements).

Comment: @FelixKling do a ctrl find for the line I pasted.. http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: Last time: You are talking about `$(...).each`, I am talking about `$.each`, which is what the OP is using. Do you notice the difference in the URLs? You: http://api.jquery.com/each/, me: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. I can also quote for you: *"The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array."* I hope that's settled now.

Comment: Why aren't people using VanillaJS is mystery

Comment: `$.each(iterable, callback)` is perfectly fine for this purpose, and it is not the same as `$('whatever selector').each(callback)`. It might be slightly less efficient than `.forEach` but it is completely crossbrowser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
self.buildRelationships = function () {
        relationships = [];
        relationships[0] = [];
        relationships[1] = [];
        relationships[2] = [];
        relationships[3] = [];
        relationships[0][0] = self.name();

        var recursive = function(level) {

            return function(i, child) {
               relationships[level] = relationships[level] || [];

               relationships[level].push(child.name());
               $.each(child.children(), recursive(level + 1));
            }
        }

        $.each(self.children(), recursive(1));
    }
```

Comment: Lots? We are talking bytes per level here. By the looks of it he is anticipating 4 levels. In this situation I wouldn't be concerned. Clearly if we are looking to go into thousands of levels a recursive solution would not be the way to go, but OP asked for recursive, so I give recursive.

Comment: I assume I can add "relationships[i] = []" to the recursive function?

Comment: I think you would prefer to do relationships[level] = []. Have edited it in.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant.  Thanks.

Comment: This works great but adds an empty generation on the end.   Easy fix though.  Thanks.

Comment: Good point. Have updated to only add a generation if there are children. Pleasure!

Comment: I'm having some issues... it seems to be reusing i and overwriting anything it already processed on the current generation.  Not sure if that makes sense, but basically one leg of my tree isn't populating and I don't know why.

Comment: Doh, yes of course. The value of i resets back to zero for each branch. It is not good to reuse this to index the relationships array as it just overwrites the previous branches data. Have updated to just push the name onto the array which fixes it. I should have spotted that one..

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach it:

```
self.buildRelationships = function () {
    var relationships = [];
    addToLevel(self, 0);
    return relationships;

    function addToLevel(node, levelIndex) {
        $.each(node.children(), function (i, child) {
            if (relationships.length <= levelIndex) { relationships.push([]) }
            relationships[levelIndex].push(child.name()); 
            addToLevel(child, levelIndex + 1);
        });
    }
}
```

(I prefer using Underscore/Lodash for data processing, and reserving jQuery for DOM stuff. But jQuery only was assumed.)

Comment: "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

Comment: I coded this blind. If you can make a Jsfiddle I can test on, I'm glad to debug. Something's probably not initialized, but I don't have time to build a test bench to figure it out. Feel free to add the correction when you find it, if you want to use this approach.

Comment: @ScottBeeson For what it's worth, it was a fencepost error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

&for fun, here's a recursive jQuery plugin that can be invoked on a container that may or may not be a singleton "eve" creature (dependent upon whether or not the container element defines a `name` attribute) :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Jy8M/)

```
$.fn.getImps=function(imps, i)
{
    if (!$.isArray(imps)) 
        throw new Error("oook: getImps requires an empty array!");
    i=(typeof i !== "undefined" ? i : 0);

    if (this.is("[name]"))
        (imps[i] || (imps[i]=[])).push(this.attr("name")) && i++;
    this.children().each(function(){ $(this).getImps(imps,i) });
}
```

**btw**: since this is a [breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), & typically implemented using non-recursive queue-based algos..:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTAKR/)

```
//expects a singleton container id 
var getImps=function(id)
{      
    var imps=[];     
    for(var o=$(id), a; (o=o.children("[name]")).length && imps.push(a=[]);)
        o.each(function() { a.push($(this).attr("name")) });
    return imps;
}
```

(= but only saying.. =)

*Oook: um your creatures appear to be undergoing some kind of asexual reproduction ~are they maybe..  aphids?*